# Passing data between forms using serialization

Tags: c#, list, winforms, oop, serialization

Im trying to pass some objects between 2 forms using serialization. It works the first time I use it for each objects, however subsequent attempts don't pass anything over/ when I click the refresh button no new data is loaded into the box.

```
VirtualAppointments.Add(vir1.ToString());

FileStream outFile;
BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();

//open file
outFile = new FileStream("VirtualAppointments.dat", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);

bFormatter.Serialize(outFile, VirtualAppointments);

outFile.Close();

ViewAppointments viewAppointments = new ViewAppointments();


this.Close();
```

Im using the above code to pass the write the object to a .dat file and using the next block of code on the second form to read the .dat file into a list box.

```
private void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lstViewAppointments.Items.Clear();

    BinaryFormatter bFormater = new BinaryFormatter();

    FileStream inFile;

    //open file for input
    inFile = new FileStream("InPersonAppointments.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    //obtain object from file via serialization
    InPersonAppointmentsForDisplay = (List<String>)bFormater.Deserialize(inFile);

    inFile.Close();

    foreach(String s in InPersonAppointmentsForDisplay)
    {
        lstViewAppointments.Items.Add(s);
    }

  

    //open file for input
    inFile = new FileStream("VirtualAppointments.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    //obtain object from file via serialization
    VirtualAppointmentsForDisplay = (List<String>)bFormater.Deserialize(inFile);

    inFile.Close();

    foreach (String s in VirtualAppointmentsForDisplay)
    {
        lstViewAppointments.Items.Add(s);
    }

}
```

As stated above, it works for the first appointment i make for each object, but if i try to make another then when I click the refresh button, it only loads the first item from each serialization file.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want pass information between two forms of the same process using serialization? And why do want binary serialization even of they are not in the same process?

Comment: My question is similar to Reza Aghaei's - are you writing the disk file because you actually  _need_ the data to persist the next time you run the app? Or is this just a workaround you came up with to try and transport the data from one form to another?

Comment: Also please clarify the two forms. Is one of them a temporary pop-up, for example an entry form to make a single new appointment? Or do both forms exist side-by-side where the user can interact with either one at will? This makes a big difference in terms of how one might answer your question.

Comment: I thanks for all the replies. I can clarify that i do need the data to persist between opening and closing the app, and that the first form where i am attempting to write using serialization is in the showdialg mode as it must be completed first, and which point it will close and the second form will load and when the refresh button is pressed, it will read from the dat file the data input from the first form. Hope this clarifies and thanks for reading.

Comment: Give the responsibility of Save and Load to a class like VirtualAppointmentsRepository. Then in the Save and Load data using [JsonConvert](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm#JsonConvert) and read or write data from or to file using [File.ReadAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) and [File.WriteAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#system-io-file-writealltext(system-string-system-string))